# How to learn network administration

Tags: networking, network-design

I already know the basics about networks. Where can I learn intermediate-advanced networking. How to become professional in this subject. I have a lot of practice but I want to learn everything possible about networks / network administration. I apologize for my bad English.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking about physical network admin experience then you need to start playing with switches, hubs, patching etc. You can buy cheap hardware and setup something at home. Otherwise learning on the job is the best way to advance your skills. If no job then try to get an internship or volunteer somewhere to get the skills.

For software/system level skills (like vlan, bonding) you can set up several VMs and play with those. Learning from book is good but nothing beats hands on experience.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I am at the moment in a internship at a company who does this. They gave me everything that I need from cisco switches to fiber optics, rack servers etc. Ofc I am learning every day something new, but I want to learn and not miss everything. I already configured switches routerboards etc, didnt had timed to get to servers but will soon. Thx for the comment

Comment: Great. That's good start. Try to focus on specific tasks and problems. At least for me I find that easier to learn rather than a general introduction. Come up with a scenario to break/stress the system.